# How can I sort a mixed list of integers as repeating numbers with pandas like 1-2-3-4-1-2-3-4...?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a mixed list of integers from 1 to 4 (for example 100 numbers like this). I want to sort this list like (1-2-3-4-1-2-3-4 .... 1-2-3-4). Is there a simple way I can do this with numpy or pandas?

[Edited]
@Corralien's solution helped me.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("students.csv", encoding='utf-8')

df['A'] = df['Class']
df = df.assign(B=df.groupby('A').cumcount()).sort_values(['B', 'A']).drop(columns=['A','B'])

print(df.head(20))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: What's the need to sort in that way? It seems generating a list using for loop or using list constructor is enough.

Comment: @IceGriffin. yes, with for loop it can be. But for huge list it will be too slow

Comment: what about this? `a = [1,2,3,4] * 50`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a temporary column to sort your dataframe:

```
>>> df.assign(B=df.groupby('A').cumcount()).sort_values(['B', 'A']).drop(columns='B')

    A
1   1
8   2
3   3
0   4
2   1
9   2
5   3
4   4
11  1
10  2
12  3
6   4
14  1
17  2
13  3
7   4
18  1
19  2
16  3
15  4
```

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(2022)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4]*5})
df = df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)

# Output
    A
0   4
1   1
2   1
3   3
4   4
5   3
6   4
7   4
8   2
9   2
10  2
11  1
12  3
13  3
14  1
15  4
16  3
17  2
18  1
19  2
```